# Why can't byte strings be used as Docstrings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

Why is it that byte strings `b'string'` cannot be used as docstrings for classes or functions (and by extent I'm guessing modules)?

Case in point:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     b"""My Foo class for Fooing"""
>>> Foo.__doc__ is None
True
```

Similarly with functions.

For `r''`, `u''` (expected) strings it works okay. I couldn't find anything in the documentation either. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Probably because they're not actually text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by **@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams**, `b'string'` is not text, or more specifically it is not a string, it is a [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes), and I don't think you will see these referred to as "byte strings" anywhere in the Python documentation (though I could be wrong); in fact this sounds like a contradiction to me personally.

On the other hand, `r''` and `u''`, and `''` are strings (raw string literals, Unicode string literals, and string literals respectively). The first sentence for [the spec for docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#specification) states:

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.

It also specifies:

> Use `r"""raw triple double quotes"""` if you use any backslashes in your docstrings. For Unicode docstrings, use `u"""Unicode triple-quoted strings"""`.

This might not be a satisfying answer since it doesn't explain the internals of why `__doc__` in one case will return a string and in the other return `None`, or how docstrings are formed/parsed. However, I think what is happening is that you are getting `None` because you just haven't defined a docstring, but only a bytes object which you have not assigned to any variable in your class. The same thing will happen if you do:

```
class Foo:
    1
```

`1` is not being parsed as the docstring (or the `__doc__` attribute) of the class since it is not a string, and I think the same happens with the bytes literal in your example. Regardless, I think the documentation makes it clear that only "strings" can be used as docstrings, so it seems logical that bytes objects would make just as poor docstrings as an `int` or a `bool`, or any other non-string datatype. I can understand your curiosity however, especially since the [byte literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/) and string literals are so visually similar.

## tl;dr:

Bytes objects are not strings, and only strings can be used for Python docstrings.